# Unable to upload data to Firebase in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im working on this project where i have connected firebase to my app. And, everything looks fine but my data is not uploading to the database. Im also using firebase storage and my code is able to upload files to the storage. but datas are not being uploaded to the database.

The code that uploades data is like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FloatingActionButton fb;
    RecyclerView recview;
    adapter adapt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //this is the code that uploades

        model md = new model("boi2","https://www.boimela.com",0,0,0);
        DatabaseReference db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("books");
        db.child("Mgxlsd342Ft").setValue(md);


        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("books"), model.class)
                        .build();

        adapt=new adapter(options);
        recview.setAdapter(adapt);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapt.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapt.stopListening();
    }
}
```

And here is the model.java file which i used to setvalue:

```
public class model {

    String filename,fileurl;
    int num_dislikes,num_likes,num_visits;

    public model() {
    }

    public model(String filename, String fileurl, int num_dislikes, int num_likes, int num_visits) {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.fileurl = fileurl;
        this.num_dislikes = num_dislikes;
        this.num_likes = num_likes;
        this.num_visits = num_visits;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String getFileurl() {
        return fileurl;
    }

    public void setFileurl(String fileurl) {
        this.fileurl = fileurl;
    }

    public int getNum_dislikes() {
        return num_dislikes;
    }

    public void setNum_dislikes(int num_dislikes) {
        this.num_dislikes = num_dislikes;
    }

    public int getNum_likes() {
        return num_likes;
    }

    public void setNum_likes(int num_likes) {
        this.num_likes = num_likes;
    }

    public int getNum_visits() {
        return num_visits;
    }

    public void setNum_visits(int num_visits) {
        this.num_visits = num_visits;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is code that uploads data to Firebase Storage?

Comment: @AlexMamo sorry,  i edited the question and specified it more . please check again

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot see that code.

Comment: @AlexMamo oh wait u were asking for storage code. i did not show it here since its working.  the only thing that is not working is the database one

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the setValue operation, to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: To listen for the results of `setValue`, see https://gist.github.com/puf/4a94a01e3c2510298ee46d0a7f90ab75

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen completionlistener gives me the error "Cannot resolve " do i need any dependencies to make it run?